# Assignment Operator in JS: Unary or Binary?

Tags: javascript, operators, assignment-operator

we use an assignment operator `=` in order to assign a value to a variable, so the value assigned is an operand but the variable itself counts as another one?? if not is only a unary operator, that makes sense for me, but if not it's binary, but why? why the var is considered an operand in case that this will be true?

Comment: The left side is considered an operand for parsing purposes. But it acts different from all other operands, because it's a reference to a location that can be updated, not a value. In compiler terminology it's an L-value rather than an R-value.

Comment: Treating it as a binary operator means no special handling is required in a recursive descent parser with operator precedence.

Comment: The ECMAScript specification does not call the left hand side an operand, but surely you could. It's an operand whose current value plays no role (like with the comma operator), and the assignment is a side effect, just like the unary operator `++` has a side effect. Moreover, there are other assignment operators, which *do* use the current value of the lefthand side variable, so they really cannot be seen other than *binary* (like `+=`)

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing this: "if not is only a unary operator". It's a binary operator because the left operand is required. You can't write just `= 1`, you have to write `something = 1`.